# Message Box to contain Table in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

```
IEnumerable<string> peopleWithInvalidAge =
                    (from age in User
                     where age < 0
                     select name ).Distinct();

MessageBox.show("The people who have invalid age are {0}" , string.Join(", ", peopleWithInvalidAge) )
```

This displays the output as string . But what i want is that the output should be displayed in a tabular form . With Name and age when  MessageBox.show is called.

If we can highlight inside message box then also it will be great

Please help.

Comment: Seven down votes and not one comment to help the poster know why. SO should be better than that.

Comment: @JohnArlen Vague multi part question with 3 answers and no response from OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for WPF

For formatting could use Window.
You can pass the IEnumerable in the ctor.
Window.ShowDialog is modal.

[Window.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Window1 win = new Window1(new List<string> { "john", "susan" });
win.ShowDialog();

public Window1(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    Names = names;
    InitializeComponent();
}
public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; private set; }

<Window x:Class="ListViewUpdate.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Moderator there are three parts to question.
Modal, passing data, and formatting.
The other answer does not address modal or passing data to a Window.
I posted while I was creating the passing and formatting sample.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. In some discussions i figured out that we can't extend this functionality to custom message box. But from your explanation  i tried your method and it worked great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you must create  Window

Xaml

```
<my:Datagrid x:Name="test" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">  
    <my.DataGrid.Columns> 
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Your Collection" Binding="{Binding}"/>  
    </my.DataGrid.Columns> 
</my:Datagrid>
```

CodeBehind

```
public Window()  
{  
    InitializeComponent();  

    test.DataContext = peopleWithInvalidAge ;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use a window for that,with showdialg, use buttons and datagrid like you want (make it like a MessageBox) and work with Dialog result,

just an idea to do that

Comment: I figured out that there is no direct way to get the custom message in WPF to have all this functionality which i mentioned in question above. It would require to create a xaml which will be similar to Message box.