# How to display a table containing data inside message box using C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dialog, c#-3.0

Here I want data to be displayed inside a message box in a table as shown below and that message box should be activated on click. How to do that?

[image: For example this is the data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can show data from a table but I think you will be best of creating a new form and using `ShowDialog()` then you can use any control as you desire. Visit this link, it will help you:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805142/message-box-to-contain-table-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I did not get why are you using message box only .You can use a new windows form to do the same task which will be very much easy to implement and you can customize that one based on you requirement .
To create a new window form you just need to pass the reference of the first form to other .
lets say that you have two forms parent and child.
then in child constructor define it as following:

```
public child(parent parentref);
```

and then from parent code just create a object like

```
child childobj=new child(this)
```

Hope this will work